# Alternative way to read json with Newtonsoft.json-mapped to C#.net models

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Apologies for not giving the best/appropriate title for my thread, If you have a better title than me, will be glad to update it.

My current issue is that I have to work on an existing code that uses Newtonsoft.JSON that reads json from .JSON file(provided from 3rd party source). It is mapped to an existing class as well. Im not sure if this is the right way by doing IF-ELSE just to get to the proper json node, maybe someone would have their other options/better approach than mine. Thank you.

This is not the exact code, but I replicated it related to my issue.

PET.JSON File:(JSON File is provided by 3rd party, structure/schema is same like the example below, and it is their format ever since-no permission to change JSON format)

```
{
  "Pet": {
    "Dog": {
      "cute": true,
      "feet": 4
    },
    "Bird": {
      "cute": false,
      "feet": 2
    }
  }
}
```

The Pet Class & subclasses  (this is 3rd party standard structure, i dont have permission to modify it)

```csharp
public class Pet
{
    public Dog dog { get; set; }
    public Bird bird { get; set; }

    public class Dog {
        public bool cute { get; set; }
        public int feet { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bird
    {
        public bool cute { get; set; }
        public int feet { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Pet Reader  (I am required to use this Deserialized Json Object mapped to the models above, don't have permission to modify their implementation 'yet' I'll have to manage myself on how to use the return value of ReadPetJSON())

```csharp
public static Pet ReadPetJSON()
{
    string JSON_TEXT = File.ReadAllText("PET.JSON");
    Pet pet = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pet>(JSON_TEXT);
    return pet;
}
```

**Update: 
I found out about using Reflection, and I can pass a variable name to find the PropertyName. Thank you all for your help and inputs, I appreciated it**

http://mcgivery.com/c-reflection-get-property-value-of-nested-classes/

```csharp
// Using Reflection
Pet pet = ReadPetJSON();

// Search Bird > feet using 'DOT' delimiter
string searchBy = "bird.feet"

foreach (String part in searchBy.Split('.'))
{
    if (pet == null) { return null; }

    Type type = pet.GetType();
    PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(part);
    if (info == null) { return null; }  // or make a catch for NullException

    pet = info.GetValue(pet, null);
}

var result = pet.ToString(); // Object result in string
Console.WriteLine("Bird-Feet: {0}", result);
```

Output:

```
Bird-Feet: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm thinking like this, but I know it's not possible.

Yes, yes its possible by below code.

You have to `Querying` your json like

```
string JSON_TEXT = File.ReadAllText("PET.JSON");

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(JSON_TEXT);

//This is your search term
string search = "Dog";  //or "Bird", or "Lion", or "Tiger", or "Eagle" or anything that are present it your json

bool cute = (bool)jObject["Pet"][search]["cute"];
int feet = (int)jObject["Pet"][search]["feet"];

string temp = $"My {search} is cute = {cute} and feet = {feet} ";

//If you want it in your strongly type then
Dog dog = jObject["Pet"][search].ToObject<Dog>();
Bird bird = jObject["Pet"][search].ToObject<Bird>();
```

**Output:**

[image]

**In above code**

["Pet"] => 0 st position level node of your json.

[search] => 1 st position level node of your json.

["cute"] or ["feet"]  => 2 nd position level node of your json and many more as your json depth

You can find more about `Querying Json` [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Comment: @batuzai04123, view answer might be it help you :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, but based from what I said above, the implementation of NEWTONSOFT.JSON and the model mapping is the one we are required to use.

Your solution is however great for those who wants to try with this approach and I like it :)

Comment: Does this help you `Dog dog = jObject["Pet"][Pet_Name].ToObject<Dog>();`

Comment: See my updated thread above. with that code of yours, i'm not sure if why would I convert it to Object again? since `jObject["Pet"][Pet_Name]` will already return the string value itself.

Comment: I get it now ershoaib by using the type-object again thank you very much. this is the simplest of all using JObject  I recommend this solution to everyone.

Comment: If you think its really helpful then its your choice to accept this answer and vote up or not. Your post really good and challenging, I added in my favorite list and I vote up to your post :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can try these classes instead, then loop on the Pet list.

```
  public class JsonParsed
{
    public Dictionary<string, Attribute> Pet { get; set; } 
}

public class Attribute
{
    public bool cute { get; set; }
    public int feet { get; set; }
}
```

The key contains the name of the pet, and the Attribute will contain the other properties.

```
  var json = @"{'Pet': {'Dog': {'cute': true,'feet': 4},'Bird': {'cute': 
  false,'feet': 2}}}";
  var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonParsed>(json);
 foreach (var element in obj.Pet)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(element.Key  + " has " + element.Value.feet);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, may I ask where did you get the collection/list 'obj.Pet'?
I'm quite confused on how to start with yours, but still thank you.

Comment: yes, sorry about that. I missed a line. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

This type of structure with same properties is not easy to maintain according to OOP and other design principles.
If you can change the classes and JSON structure then I would recommend following sample structure.

```
[{
      cute : true, 
      feet : 4, 
      type : "dog"
      }, {
      cute : true, 
      feet : 2, 
      type : "bird"
 }]
```

And instead of a class with Bird and Dog child classes, we can have an List of Pet class objects.

```
class Pet
{
    int Feet {get; set; }
    string Type { get; set; }
    bool Cute { get; set; }
}
```

now in your method where you expect to read it, you can read Json and return the list to be searched.

```
List<Pet> pets = ReadPetJson();
string Pet_Name = DummyPetName(); // Returns string 'Bird' or 'Dog' etc.
var matchedPet = pets.FirstOrDefault(x => 
x.Type.ToLower() == Pet_Name);
if (matchedPet != null)
   return matchedPet.Cute;
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs,

If you can recall from the intro of this thread, the "current" implementation is set by 3rd party. JSON file is provided by another team and their formatting has been like that ever since.

If the JSON can't be modified, so is the model also. 
But again thank you.

Comment: And even the models itself have other properties already set and looks like they will have it like that.

I found the Reflection library, I might give it a shot.

Comment: I found a great article that uses Reflection library, see updated thread for your reference. Thank you for your input. I agree to you that this JSON format is hard to map with models due to complex structure, but again, we don't have a choice since it is the agreed standards between our team and the client.

Comment: @batuzai04123  I ignore the part about 3rd party. Well then Reflection is the way to go. But this seriously causes issues as more and more classes become part of a single object.

Comment: Sorry about that I gave a dummy JSON example. So far the JSON we have is mapped to 5 classes only A, B, C, D, E. and Each classes have their own array of properties-attributes as well. and this amounts to hundred to thousands of array contents depending on the request we made. So to be clear, it's not exactly it will increase again, I just assume if anytime soon they decided to add another category. Thanks.

Comment: @batuzai04123 Okay, then you might as well discuss this maintain-ability with your seniors and help them to plan the future development smoother. Anyway. thanks for discussing internal situation with me.